# Regex match first word after last matching /

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

> /job/IT/job/DECISION/job/Run_Console/configSubmit by username1234

and I would like to get only the first word after the last "/". currently I'm not understanding how to do that. can you help me?
e.g. using

> ([^/]*)$

I will match the whole string "configSubmit by username1234".

just an update: probably I need to anchor my regex to the fact that string starts with /job

Comment: `/(?!.*\/)\w*/` with negative look-ahead assertion

Comment: Use `.*/(\S+)` and grab the value in Group 1. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTzeGj/1). In PCRE, Boost or Onigmo, `.*/\K\S+` will work, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTzeGj/2)

Comment: In Grok, you exactly use named capturing groups, `.*/(?<fieldname>\S+)`

Answer (score 0):

You need find word after this you need no \ before end of string

```
(\w*) - word
[^/]*$ - no \ before end of string
(\w*)[^/]*$

https://regex101.com/r/p8iweu/1
```

Comment: using (\w*)[^/]*$ I will get the correct value in Group 1 but I'm not that in grok usage (into Logstash) I can use Groups.

Comment: if you want without group let use lookahead and lookbehind. (?<=/) - check are / before word. (?=[^/]*$) no \ before end of string
Together (?<=/)(\w*)(?=[^/]*$)
https://regex101.com/r/p8iweu/2/